# How to send responsive array from android using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to call web service which receives responsive array. I am sending Hash map with values using retrofit in android but it is giving me 500 internal server error.Following is my code:
`@POST("/save")
    public void CreateAccount(
            @Body Map<String, String> data,
             Callback<Response> callback);`

Comment: what is a responsive array?

Comment: responsive array in php which consist of key value pairs

Comment: you mean **Associative arrays** ? if so, then you are looking for a key-value structure, if the map is not working try to fill the keys in a JsonObject then send `jsonObj.toString()` to the server otherwise you need to get a request sample of how the data should look like when sent to server

Comment: tried it too not working

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can do this with Retrofit 2

Interface:

```
@POST("/save")
    Call<JsonElement> CreateAccount(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

Request code:

```
//create JsonObject with key-pair values
JsonObject root = new JsonObject();
root.addProperty("key1", "value1");
root.addProperty("key2", "value2");
//get is as string
String resultJson = root.toString();
//parse it to RequestBody type
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), resultJson);
//create adapter
Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
IConstructSecureAPI service = restAdapter.create(IConstructSecureAPI.class);

Call<JsonElement> result = service.CreateAccount(requestBody);
result.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonElement> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
            JsonObject withResponse = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(response.message());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```